# Using SQLAlchemy, determine which list values are not in a DB column

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlalchemy

Using SQLAlchemy, given a list, I'd like to determine which values in the list are not present in a given column in an sqlite DB table. One way to do it is the following:

```
def get_user_ids_not_in_DB(self, user_ids):
    query__belongs = User_DB.user_id.in_(user_ids)
    select__user_ids_in_DB = self.SQL_Helper.db.query(User_DB.user_id).filter(query__belongs)
    user_ids_in_DB = zip(*select__user_ids_in_DB.all())[0]
    return list(set(user_ids) - set(user_ids_in_DB))
```

Is there a faster/more efficient way to accomplish the same thing?

Answer (score 2):

Select all users then outer join it to an Aliased the User_db object   Then add a filter for non-Aliased user_id's that are null.

```
   # an alias to a subquery on a  table. All user ids in you list
   ualias = aliased(User_DB, User_DB.user_id.in_(user_ids))

   results = self.SQL_Helper.db.query(User_DB.user_id)\
                 .outerjoin(ualias, ualias.user_id == User_DB.user_id)\
                 .filter(ualias.user_id == None)
```

Pardon typos, but that the gist of it.

Comment: The identity operator cannot be overloaded, so `ualias.user_id is None` evaluates to `False` python side and so you have `WHERE false` in SQL. Use `ualias.user_id.is_(None)`, or `ualias.user_id == None`, which SQLAlchemy converts to `IS` automatically.

Comment: @IljaEverilä Whoops! Good catch.  I've updated my answer based on your comment

Answer (score 1):

That's the most efficient I can think of (quite close to yours):

```
from future_builtins import zip, map
from operator import itemgetter

def get_user_ids_not_in_DB(self, user_ids):
    unique_ids = set(user_ids)
    query__belongs = User_DB.user_id.in_(unique_ids)
    select__user_ids_in_DB = self.SQL_Helper.db.query(User_DB.user_id).filter(query__belongs)
    user_ids_in_DB = set(map(itemgetter(0), select__user_ids_in_DB))
    return (unique_ids - user_ids_in_DB)
```